# scroll div in opposite vertical direction between given coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".myDiv").css("top", Math.max(-105, 0 - $(this).scrollTop()));
});
```

Using the above code `myDiv` scrolls UP from `0px` to `-105px` when I scroll down. The only change I would like to this is that `myDiv` scrolls down from `-105px` to `0px` when I scroll down.

Any help, please?

Comment: Put a fiddle example...

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log(Math.max(-105, 0 - $(this).scrollTop()));
  $(".myDiv").animate({
    top: $(this).scrollTop()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='height:200px;border:1px solid;position:relative;background:#ff6600' class='myDiv'>mydiv</div>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
<P>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind 'mousewheel' event and check for originalEvent.wheelDelta.

Code:

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event){
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0)
        //up
    else
        //down
});
```